# Delete entries with only one observation in a group

Tags: r

Here I would like to remove entries that have only one-entry for a given city by date. So for instance, I would like to remove the New York and San Francisco entries, since they only have 1 observation on 4-11, and 4-12.

```
day                          City                  age
4-10                        Miami                   30
4-10                        Miami                   23
4-11                        New York                24
4-12                        San Francisco           30
```

Note Dataset is called DG

I tried using a for loop to find the days and get an idea of the number of entries per division per day, but I'm not sure how to work with arrays in R.
countx =0

```
D = unique(DG$day)
for (i in 1:length(D))
{
    for (j in 1:length(DG$age))
    {
      if (DG$day[j] == D{i]
      {
      countx[j] = 1
      }
      else
      {
      countx[j] = 0
      }
    }
Binded <- cbind(countx, DG)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With your sample data

```
DG <- read.csv(text="day,City,age
4-10,Miami,30
4-10,Miami,23
4-11,New York,24
4-12,San Francisco,30")
```

you could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DG %>% group_by(day,City) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

or base R

```
DG[ave(rep(1, nrow(DG)), DG$day, DG$City, FUN=length)>1,]
```

both return

```
   day  City age
1 4-10 Miami  30
2 4-10 Miami  23
```

Or you could use `data.table` (as suggested by @Frank)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DG)[,if (.N>1) .SD, by=.(City,day)]
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, worked like a charm, although I have a question, how does the FUN comment know to refer to looking at the average?

Comment: Using `FUN=length` counts the number of observations in each day/city group. It has nothing to with averages.

Answer (score 4):

MrFlick's answer is (as usual) hard to top, but here's my longer version, which instead serves as a great way to get in some practice with `dplyr`.

Here's the dataframe:

```
DG <- data.frame(day=c('4-10', 4-10', '4-11', '4-12'), City=c('Miami', 'Miami', 'New York', 'San Francisco'), age=c(30, 23, 23, 30))
```

Using `group_by`, we group the cities together, then pipe the groupings into `summarize` using `n()`, which is a handy dplyr function.

```
DG1 <- DG %>%
  group_by(City, day) %>%
  summarize(n=n())
#          City  day n
#         Miami 4-10 2
#      New York 4-11 1
# San Francisco 4-12 1
```

Turn `DG1` into a regular dataframe, just to be on the safe side:

```
DG2 <- data.frame(DG1)
```

...and then we get rid of unwanted rows via `filter`, based on what appeared more than once.

```
DG3 <- filter(DG2, n>1)
#City  day  n
#Miami 4-10 2
```

Next, use `select` to get columns (whereas we just used `filter` to get rows). This just gets rid of the column `n`.

```
DG4 <- select(DG3, City, day)
#City  day
#Miami 4-10
```

Finally, we use `filter` on the original dataframe to get all the cities that have multiple occurances. These cities with multiple occurances now live in `DG4` (hence `City==DG4$City`):

```
DG5 <- filter(DG, City==DG4$City)
#day  City   age
#4-10 Miami  30
#4-10 Miami  23
```

Again, I'd go with MrFlick's answer, but if you feel like a more circuitous route with a few more `dplyr` functions, you might want to give this a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dataset with cities that only appears once, then delete those cities from the original dataset.

```
library(dlypr)
city_once=count(DG,DG$City)
```

city_once will look like this:

```
date    City         age
4-11  New York       24
4-12  San Francisco  30
```

then delete those cities from the original dataset DG:

```
City_more=DG[!DG$City %in% city_once$City,]
```

the City_more dataset will look like this:

```
day     City   age
4-10   Miami    30
4-10   Miami    23
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `duplicated` avoiding the need for any type of grouping.

Based on column positions

```
DG[duplicated(DG[1:2]) | duplicated(DG[1:2], fromLast = TRUE) , ]
#   day  City age
#1 4-10 Miami  30
#2 4-10 Miami  23
```

OR based on column names

```
DG[duplicated(DG[c("day", "City")]) | 
   duplicated(DG[c("day", "City")], fromLast = TRUE) ,]
```

**data**

```
DG <- data.frame(day= c('4-10', '4-10', '4-11', '4-12'), 
                 City=c('Miami', 'Miami', 'New York', 'San Francisco'), 
                 Age=c(30, 23, 23, 30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```