# Dropping rows with sequence of conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is in relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468401/delete-entries-with-only-one-observation-in-a-group-in-r) one in the link. Please mark duplicate (and redirect me please) if anyone else has asked this extension (my search was futile).

I have a huge data over many id and time. 
**example data:**

```
id <- c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c', 'd')
time <- c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002, 2003,2003,2003,2003)
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA,10,11,12,12)
y <- c(NA,2,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,7,8,9,NA,10,11,12,12)
z <- c(NA,2,3,NA,4,5,NA,NA,7,8,9,NA,NA,11,12,12)
w <- c(NA,2,3,NA,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA,NA,11,12, 12)
mydata <- data.frame(id, time, x, y, z, w)
```

**Question:**
I am trying to write a chunk of code which will do the following:

1. Keep the ids' in priority order.
   That is, in the example data above, id b is a priority as that has no data missing over time. Then keep id c as that has 2 years with all data and one missing in 2000 and 2 missing in 2001.
2. Drop ids' in priority order. d will be dropped and a will be kept.
3. I have way too many ids so this code should iterate over all of them and all the years.

**Initial tries:** Using the solution above with some tinkering did not work for me. I can drop the id ds whenever they are NA, but for other years the variables may be populated and in that case I would want to impute a limited number of missing values. So, say d is available for atleast 6 years, I keep d.

Comment: I'm not certain I'm totally following how you are choosing which id's to keep.  It might help to show what you want the result to look like.  Does the problem boil down to calculating the number of missing values and then keeping the id's with the fewest?

Comment: Hello @aosmith. Actually I want to keep the ids' that have the fewest missing values over time. But not the ones that have largest gaps in the values over time, i.e., say over 15 years of data an id has 10 years of missing values over all the 4 variables, then I drop it. Does that make it a little clearer?

Comment: @econbuffin2019 Please add the result you expect.

Comment: Hi @PierreLapointe the result I expect in the given example is all the rows with b and c.